# Spark HDFS Direct Read vs Hive External table read

Tags: apache-spark-sql

We have couple HDFS directories in which data stored in delimited format. These directories created as one directory per ingestion date. These directories added as a partitions to a Hive external table.

Directory structure:

/data/table1/INGEST_DATE=20180101

/data/table1/INGEST_DATE=20180102

/data/table1/INGEST_DATE=20180103 etc.

Now we want to process this data in spark job.  From the program I can directly read these HDFS directories by giving exact directory path(Option 1) or I can read from Hive into a data frame and process(Option 2).

I would like to know if there is any significant difference in following Option1 or Option2.  Please let me know if need any other details.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did the answer help in your understanding?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a subset of the columns, then that it is only possible via spark.sql. In your use case I don't think there will be a significant difference.

With Spark SQL you can get Partition pruning automatically.